# NodeJs consulta no SQL Server com Like

Tags: javascript, node.js

Estou começando algumas rotinas com node.js e sqlserver.

A minha rotina em ColdFusion é uma consulta de materiais e chama a api node via cfhttp.

Preciso passar como parâmetro para a API dois ou mais campos para serem filtrados.
Estou testando primeiro com um campo e a minha select não faz o registro corretamente por causa do uso do LIKE.

Olhem a minha rotina:

```
router.get('/materialNome/:material', (req, res) =>{
    let filter = '';
    if(req.params.material)filter= ' WHERE NOME_SERVICO LIKE' + '%' +(req.params.material)+'%';
    execSQLQuery('SELECT ID_MATERIAL,ID_FAMILIA,NOME_SERVICO FROM SERVICO.SERVICOSMATERIAL' + filter, res);
})
```

Não estou sabendo usar o like no Node.

Alguém poderia exemplificar?

Answer (score 0):

Você não esta usando corretamente as aspas e vai dar problema.
Segue exemplo correto de concatenação usando aspas simples e dupla.

```
var nome = req.body.nome;
const query = "SELECT * FROM cadastros_gerais WHERE razao_social LIKE '%" + nome + "%'  AND ativo = 1";
```

O Like precisa ter aspas para indiciar um valor de string, dai você pode usar os 2 tipos de aspas, uma para concatenar e outra pra indicar a string do LIKE.

Comment: Só tem que tomar cuidado porque este código provavelmente está suscetível à SQL Injection.

Answer (score 0):

Utilize [`Template String`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/template_strings) para visualizar mais facilmente o erro na sua `query`:

```
router.get('/materialNome/:material', (req, res) =>{
  let filter = '';
  if(req.params.material)filter= ` WHERE NOME_SERVICO LIKE '%${req.params.material}%'`;
  execSQLQuery(`SELECT ID_MATERIAL,ID_FAMILIA,NOME_SERVICO FROM SERVICO.SERVICOSMATERIAL ${filter}`, res);
})
```

---

> [**`Template String`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/template_strings)
>
> Template literals são literais string que permitem expressões embutidas. Você pode usar string multi-linhas e interpolação de string com elas. Elas eram chamadas "template strings" nas versões anteriores à especificação ES2015.
>
> **Sintaxe**
>
> ```
> `corpo de texto`
> `texto linha 1
>  texto linha 2`
> `texto string ${expression} texto string`
> tag `texto string ${expression} texto string`
> ```

Comment: Só tem que tomar cuidado porque este código provavelmente está suscetível à SQL Injection.

Comment: @LuizFelipe sim, mas como ele não informou qual a biblioteca que está usando não conseguimos consultar se há alguma forma com parâmetros para realizar a substituição